# Can't install "composer require pusher/pusher-php-server" in laravel 9 using private github repo

Tags: php, git, composer-php, laravel-9, pusher

I got this error when try to run "composer require pusher/pusher-php-server" in laravel 9.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-form-helper, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
- It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

```
Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I tried to add repositories and change version of my spatie/laravel-form-helper from "1.8.0" to * and myusername/myprojectname from "2.0.0" to * but still didn't work

This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "repositories":[
        {
           "type": "vcs",
           "url": "https://github.com/MyUsername/MyProjectName.git"
        }
     ],
     "require-all": true,
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "ladumor/laravel-pwa": "^0.0.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
        "spatie/laravel-google-fonts": "^1.2",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-form-helper": "*",
        "myusername/myprojectname": "^2.0.0"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-form-helper": "^2.16"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require-dependencies": true,
    "require-dev-dependencies": true
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the error is in any way related to Pusher? `spatie/laravel-form-helper` is not available - where did you get it from? Packagist does not list it, nor could I find it at Spatie's repositories on Github?